# $set->url/login.php with a Target="_top"

Tags: php

I have a blog were a added code is not working in
I'm looking for a solution `Location: $set->url/login.php`
with an `target="_top"`

```
<?php
include "/inc/init.php";
include '/lib/pagination.class.php';


if(!$user->islg()) {
header("Location: $set->url/login.php");
exit;
}

$page->title = "Profile View";

$presets->setActive("dashboard");

echo '
<legend></legend>
<div class="jumbotron">';
?>
```

Comment: You can't interpolate strings like that without `${...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Window-target

```
header('Window-target: _top');
header("Location: $set->url/login.php");
```

Comment: Thanks for your Support Arzoo